# ADC settling time

Tags: operational-amplifier, adc

According to TI's *[Switched-Capacitor ADC Analog Input Calculations](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slaa036/slaa036.pdf)* application note you can select resistor Rs such that the signal settles within an error band given sample time Ts.

Once one has this value Rs, how does it relate to the actual op-amp specifications? Is this just Ro of the op amp?

What does an op-amp's bandwidth have to do with settling time?

What are some tips selecting an op-amp?

Answer (score 1):

Look at figure 2 in that app note.

[image]

The settling time shown there assumes a step input Vs, which is not practical in the real world.  Any realizable op-amp is going to have its own resistance, that is in series with Ri in figure 1.  This additional resistance is going to increase the RC time constant, thus increasing the settling time.

This is one of reasons that, as a rule of thumb, you want a driving op amp that has a low output resistance.